# jQuery: element is not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I am working on a search functionality and would like to show an info "No search result" in each of four tabs (tab-pane). Instead, the 'No Search Results' message is shown multiple times. I remove the div every time before it is created.
See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RATWJ/).

The HTML structure is like this:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="Incoming">

    <div class="accordion" id="accordionIncoming"> </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Escalation">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionEscalation"> </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Outgoing">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionOutgoing"> </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="Manual-tasks">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionManual-tasks"> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The relevant javascript is this:

```
...
else if (searchTerm !== "" && countNoResults === 0 && v.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
            $('#well-exists').remove();
            $('.tab-pane').append('<div class="well well-small" id="well-exists">No search results.</div>');

        }
```

UPDATE: I solved it by using show/hide instead. 
The HTML added to tab-content:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="well well-small" id="well-exists" style="display:none;">No search results.      </div>
```

And the javascript:

```
    $.each(cachedText, function (i, v) {
        if (searchTerm.length > 0 && v.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) {

            $infoPanels.eq(i).show().parentsUntil('.accordion').addClass("in").show();
            $('.accordion-body').addClass("in").css('height', 'auto');
            countNoResults++;

            if (v.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) {
            $('#well-exists').hide();  
            }
        }
        else if (searchTerm !== "" && countNoResults === 0 && v.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
            console.log("show");
            $('#well-exists').show();


        }         
    });
```

Comment: Put all the relevant details directly in your question.

Comment: You are using append, which adds a new div every time someone types a character. A better approach would be to show/hide a "no search results." div based on the results.

Comment: +1 @Fuzzley, or just have the div be empty and set its text.

Comment: @Fuzzley Thank you! I used your suggestion with show/hide and it worked. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the message multiple times because you have multiple elements with the class 'tab-pane', and because you are doing the appending of the 'No Search Results' div once for every entry in cachedText.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. So, the reason I use them for each pane is that I want them displayed in each tab. And I remove the div every time before I create a new one.

Comment: You end up having several elements with the ID of well-exists, but the jQuery selector $('#well-exists') only returns one, and therefore only the first one it finds gets deleted.

Comment: Good to know. I solved it with show/hide as suggested in the comment above. Thank you again.